# IE11 + on paste event - relative path images not loading

Tags: c#, jquery

On IE11 browser i have a problem with loading images.

On paste event - i will be generating HTML as

```
$("<img></img>").attr('src', ('../Images/Add.gif')
```

And the images are not coming on the UI - showed as "X".

I did try by giving full path and it started working - image is loading properly.

Other IE versions I did not face this problem (problem specific to IE11).

Can any one please help on this?